# Firefox freezes too often, nothing useful in logs

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, intel

Ubuntu totally freezes when using Firefox, can't access TTY and REISUB doesn't work.

- Xubuntu 15.04 x86-64 (up to date/proposed not active)
- Firefox 38
- Intel Celeron J1900 with Intel Graphics (Bay Trail)
- 4GB RAM

Difficult to target the problem because it may occur after 5 minutes or after 10 hours of Firefox usage. I tried a new profile with hardware acceleration off, smooth scroll off and uninstalled flash but same thing.

Here's `syslog` (2 hours before freeze, freeze/hard reboot at 23:30)

```
Jun  8 21:17:01 heaven CRON[4228]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  8 22:17:01 heaven CRON[4590]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  8 22:52:15 heaven kernel: [18841.243021] perf interrupt took too long (5003 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
Jun  8 23:17:01 heaven CRON[5077]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="702" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 110
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd-modules-load[201]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd-modules-load[201]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd-modules-load[201]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd-modules-load[201]: Module 'fuse' is builtin
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd-udevd[279]: starting version 219
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Created slice system-ifup.slice.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven systemd[1]: Starting system-ifup.slice.
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.4"
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.3"
Jun  8 23:30:26 heaven mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

I've recently added *i915.enable_rc6=0* to grub to prevent video players to freeze the system with harware acceleration activated (due to [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88012)) so I've reverted the change to see if Firefox is affected but with RC6 activated i have both freezes for video players and Firefox so i don't think it's related but I want to be as specific as possible for those who can help me.

Edit 06/10 > After more research, it seems `disable intel-pstate` could help me, so i added `intel_pstate=disable` to boot parameters in GRUB. Since I started the computer, no crashes but I'll wait a little longer before classifying the case as solved.